# Time-series prediction by separating dependent and independent variables

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose, I have this kind of data:

```
date                  pollution  dew  temp   press wnd_dir  wnd_spd  snow  rain    
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     0
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     0
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     0
2010-01-02 03:00:00      181.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     0
2010-01-02 04:00:00      138.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2     0
```

I want to apply neural network for the time-series prediction of `pollution`.
It should be noted that other variables: `dew,  temp,   press, wnd_dir,  wnd_spd,  snow, rain` are independent variables of `pollution`.
If I implement LSTM as in [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) the LSTM learns for all the variables as independent; and the model can predict for all variables.

But it is not necessary to predict for all independent variables, the only requirement is `pollution`, a dependent variable.

Is there any way to implement LSTM or another better architecture which learns and predict for only the dependent variable, by considering other independent variables as independent, and perform much better prediction of pollution?

Comment: Isn't the example only for `pollution` already?

Comment: i do not think so, why do you think so?

Comment: Let me answer and see if you agree ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the example is predicting only `pollution` already. If you see the `reframed`:

```
   var1(t-1)  var2(t-1)  var3(t-1)  var4(t-1)  var5(t-1)  var6(t-1)  \
1   0.129779   0.352941   0.245902   0.527273   0.666667   0.002290
2   0.148893   0.367647   0.245902   0.527273   0.666667   0.003811
3   0.159960   0.426471   0.229508   0.545454   0.666667   0.005332
4   0.182093   0.485294   0.229508   0.563637   0.666667   0.008391
5   0.138833   0.485294   0.229508   0.563637   0.666667   0.009912

   var7(t-1)  var8(t-1)   var1(t)
1   0.000000        0.0  0.148893
2   0.000000        0.0  0.159960
3   0.000000        0.0  0.182093
4   0.037037        0.0  0.138833
5   0.074074        0.0  0.109658
```

The `var1` seems to be `pollution`. As you see, you have the values from the previous step `(t-1)` for all variables and the value for the current step `t` for `pollution` (`var1(t)`).

This last variable is what the example is feeding as `y`, as you can see in lines:

```
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
```

So the network should be already predicting only on `pollution`.

Comment: there are also other variables: var2(t-1),  var3(t-1),  var4(t-1) , var5(t-1)  var6(t-1). I could not understand why it is not predicting other variables?

Comment: Also what kind of relation does it consider between dependent and independent variables?

Comment: Those variables are used as `x`, so the network learns from previous values of those variables in order to predict future values of `pollution`.